# Is it possible to call return with pipe operator after function call?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm **wondering** what would be the best/cleanest way to write this pseudocode in javascript (ES6) :

```
function toto(....){
    ....
    callSomething() || return ; // should break toto() here
    ....
}
```

*Context : I saw this in a commented bunch of code, and it seemed very strange.
I'm not experimented enough in JS to figure out what it does (mixing logic op and statement).
After your answers, i understand that this commented code does nothing since it's not at least valid.*

Comment: `if (!callSomething()) return;`?

Comment: No it is not, because `return` is a *statement*, not an *expression*. You have to use an `if` construction.

Comment: Why does everything need to be condensed to a one-liner, even control-flow altering statements…?

Comment: All three comments should be part of an answer, guys.

Comment: pipe operator!? || this is Logical OR part from Logical operators in JS. No you cant!

Comment: @YordanNikolov removed wrong tag

Comment: @deceze just wondering, not for prod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`return` is a statement, not an expression, so it cannot be abused in this way.

Stop trying to find new and inventive ways to condense your code into a single-line program that nobody can maintain using endless "tricks".

The only sensible way to do what you're trying to do is this:

```
if (!callSomething()) {
   return;
}
```

… or switch to Perl. :)

Comment: Indeed, seems the most simple way. Thanks :) When you write " trying to find new and inventive ways to condense your code" -> nope, just wondering... "nobody can maintain" -> it's my job, i know the problem :/

Comment: See edit, i added the context of my question. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Benj: Good stuff